# Orthogonal subspace of x in P2

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods, orthogonality

Question. Explicitly define the subspace of ${P}^2$ orthogonal to $y(x) = x$ given $<f, g> = \int_{-1}^{1} {fg} dx $

For this one I just applied the formula from orthogonal projections :

$p_n(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n {<f, h_i > \over  <h_i, h_i>} h_i(x)$         in which $h_i = x^i, i=0,1,2$

In the end I got the result $p_n(x) =x$ which seems strange to me since I'm saying the function is the only subspace of $P^2$ orthogonal to itself. If we check the inner product it makes sense as it will be $<f,g> = 0$ but shouldn't I be worried about this result as it seems an obvious case? Maybe I'm just expecting the simplicity of common inner products I should have left aside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a lot easier to do the straight-forward way instead. Figure out directly from the definition which $a, b, c$ give $\langle ax^2 + bx + c, x\rangle = 0$:
$$
\int_{-1}^1 (ax^2+bx+c)\cot x\,dx = \int_{-1}^1(ax^3 + bx^2 + cx)dx\\
= \frac23b
$$
For this to be $0$ we need $b = 0$ and nothing else. Which is to say, $a$ and $c$ can be anything, and the subspace you're after is
$$
\operatorname{Span}(x^2, 1) = \{ax^2 + c\mid a, c\in \Bbb R\}
$$

Answer (score 0):

A polynomial $p(x)=ax^2 +bx+c$ of $P^2$ is orthogonal to $x$ if and only if

$$\int_{-1}^1 x p(x) \ dx=0$$ which simply gives $b=0$. So the orthogonal of $x$ is the linear subspace of the polynomials $ax^2+c$ where $a,c$ are real numbers.